# Small letters in superscript in Gmail subject line

Tags: gmail, text-formatting

Twitter sends email notifications with the subject in small letters raised above the base line:

[image: image how it looks]

How can we do this in our messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They insert [Unicode superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) in subject line.  You can do, too: there are sub/superscript generators online, for example [this one](https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator). Example:

> da_667ᴺᵉᶜᵏᵇᵉᵃʳᵈ ᵗᵒᵒ ʰᵃᶦʳʸ ᵗᵒ ʰᶦᵈᵉ Tweeted:

In principle, one can type these directly but you'd have to know the Unicode code points and how to use them to enter characters on your device.